# Linux Name Resolution-Samba or Bind

Tags: linux, dns, samba, bind

I'm trying to make sure that all my PC's(with any OS) & mobile devices can see my Linux computer's name(x100 for example). Is using Samba the best option for this? Or if I install a DNS Server such as Bind, would this be the better option?  Or maybe there is an option I do not know of?

What I'm looking for as far as a resolution to my issue is flexibility. So if I have a Windows computer, iPad, Mac, and Android device, they should all be able to resolve the linux computers IP to X100 .

Comment: Regular DNS requires configuration. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/886986/219095) on a similar question. On Windows, you’d have to install [Bonjour for Windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999?locale=en_US) (now called Bonjour Print Services).

Comment: @DanielB Yes I realize configuring Bind would take time. I'm looking for the BEST option not the quickest. Installing bonjour for Windows, Linux, and any other device to talk with a MAC (or device that uses bonjour), would take way more time.

Comment: I actually favor using Bind,over a combo of bonjour & samaba. Yet I'm trying to see if this would be the best option.

Comment: It’s not just about configuring Bind. It’s also how you’d need to point all devices in your network at this server and set up DDNS and whatnot. mDNS is, in comparison, essentially a zero-effort/zero-maintenance kind of thing. Obviously, I’m a fan of auto-configuration. ;)

Comment: So your saying that if I install zero-config mDNS ultiliy such as Avahi to my linux box (x100), I should see X100(and its services) from any device on my network?

Comment: From this https://wiki.debian.org/ZeroConf it sounds like ZeroConf utilities discover services,but do not resolve the machine host name to its current IP. I personally do not want to install a zeroconf utility on all my devices. Again, this would take way more time to do.